# Passing class from Material-UI TextField to InputBase

Tags: material-ui

`TextField` has an `InputProps` prop to pass values down to the `OutlinedInput`. But I need to pass a `className` prop down to the `InputBase`, which is the root element of `OutlinedInput`. I don't want to do this at the theme/global level. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const StyledTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
      // apply your styles here
    }
  }
})(TextField);
```

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
      // apply your styles here
    }
  }
});

const classes = useStyles();

<TextField classes={classes} />
```